How to train Logistic regression model with multiple inputs for 1 target value?
My data looks like similar to this: (the picture below is not mine, but describes perfectly my situation)

where the IDs are not unique but for each ID value I have a unique target value
The following solution has been suggested:

But sadly that solution does not work with me (I do not have only one table that has duplicate IDs), is there any other way to solve this problem?
PS:  I do not whether I should credit from where I took the picture or something like that,just mention it in the comments and I will do it, Thank you.

Hi @MoezDaly, welcome to the site. Why can't you just join the 2 tables you have to obtain a result like the second picture?

@noe hi, because I have 2 tables as such (2 with duplicate IDs like the left side of the first picture and one with the target values like the right side of the first picture) and joining the 2 tables with no target value is sadly not possible

I still fail to see why it shouldn't be possible to join the two tables on itemId. Can you elaborate?
